# Decode HTML entities in android

Tags: html, android, decode

I need to decode HTML entities, e.g. from &#246; to ö, and &amp; to &.

`URLEncoder.decode(str)` does not do the job (convert from % notations). TextUtils has a HTMLencode, but not a HTMLdecode.

Are there any function for decoding HTML entities?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4882425/1224741

Comment: see answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138127/how-to-do-url-decoding-in-java

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The [Html class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) is supposed to do that, however it is said that everything is not supported. It always worked for me but I never had ö so I can't tell for this one.
Try `Html.fromHtml(yourStr)` to get the decoded string.

Comment: It appears that in API Level 16 they have added `Html.escapeHtml`

Comment: Although it works perfectly, I code is quite complicated. Why isn't there something simple for doing this?

Comment: @sFuller Functionality wise `fromHtml != escapeHtml` (AFAICT from the android source code)

Comment: `escapeHtml`? But I want to do opposite (decode/unescape HTML)!

Comment: Since API Level 24 it is better to use `HtmlCompat.fromHtml()`

Answer (score 28):

Html.fromHtml(String html) is **deprecated** after API v24 so this is the correct way to do it

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24)
  {
       textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString , Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)));  
  }
  else
  {
       textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
  }
```

Answer (score 14):

Simply you can do that using this code

```
  Html.fromHtml(String).toString();
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

you can use WebView to represent any html text easily by following below steps.

first convert your data in html format as :

```
String res=null;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
res=Html.fromHtml(product.getDescription(),Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT).toString();
}
else{
res=Html.fromHtml(product.getDescription()).toString();
}
```

Then load your data in WebView as:

```
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, res, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove special char from string by calling

```
responsestring.replace(“special char here”, “”);
```

you can convert response into a string from htmlstring like that – 
Html.fromHtml( response string here )
But this method is depreciated on API 24 so you need to do it in a correct way-

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24)
{
    post_description.setText(Html.fromHtml( response here , Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
}
else
{
    post_description.setText(Html.fromHtml( response here ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To work around the deprecation in API v24 you can use

```
HtmlCompat.fromHtml(htmlString, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT).toString()
```