# JSON response contains characters represented as decimals

Tags: java, android, json, httpresponse

My JSON response contains characters in decimal format such as

```
My Friend&#39;s Story
```

instead of

```
My Friend's  Story
```

How do I convert them properly?

Comment: show us an example JSON string.

Comment: Ask owner of the service to fix this, it looks like a bug in service, either using HTML encoding, or passing HTML encoded content directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Decode HTML entities in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918920/decode-html-entities-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

That's simple: You can use [org.json.JSONTokener](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html) to solve your problem....

```
String json = "\"My Friend&#39;s Story\""; 
String value = (String)new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();
```

Comment: Why would that work? That's a HTML entity, not JSON quoting (which tokener would handle)

Comment: @StaxMan, unfortunately Google didn't include `XMLTokener` (which is available on org.json site. My thought is that they probably included some html decoding in the JSONTokener.