# Is there a faster way to decode html characters to a string than Html.fromHtml()?

Tags: android, html, string, decode, html-entities

I am using Html.fromHtml(STRING).toString() to convert a string that may or may not have html and/or html entities in it, to a plain text string.

This is pretty slow, I think my last calculation was that it took about 22ms on avg.  With a large batch of these it can add over a minute.  So I am looking for a faster, performance built option.

Is there anyway to speed this up or are there other decoding options available?

**Edit:**  Since there doesn't appear to be a built in method that is faster or built for performance specifically, I will reward the bounty to anyone that can point me in the direction of a library that:

- Works well with Android
- Licensed for free use
- Faster than `Html.fromHtml(String).toString();`

As a note, I already tried Jsoup with this method:  `Jsoup.parse(String).text()` and it was slower.

Comment: Actually teh Html.fromHtml was very helpful for me to decode some "ISO-8859" thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What about org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils's [unescapeHtml()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml(java.lang.String)). The library is available on [Apache](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) site.

(EDIT: June 2019 - See the comments below for updates about the library)

Comment: Works on Android: Check.  Library is reliable, free and small: Check.  Fast: Check.  This is almost 22x the speed of Html.fromHtml(String).toString();   Thanks!

Comment: There's a chance that `unescapeHtml4()` from Commons Lang 3.1 is significantly (200x) slower than `unescapeHtml()` from Commons Lang 2.6. I tested using DDMS and Traceview on Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.1, and emulator with Android 2.2. I know that Dalvik Just-In-Time is disabled when tracing, so my findings may be inaccurate. But it was enough to scare me into using Commons Lang 2.6 instead of 3.1.

Comment: I can confirm that 3.1 is slower than 2.6, at least it was when I tested it.

Comment: Profiling on a Nexus 5 with Android Marshmallow, `Html.fromHtml()` is significantly faster than commons-lang3-3.1 `unescapeHtml3()` and `unescapeHtml4()`.  There is no longer an `unescapeHtml()` method in 3.1

Comment: Ah it looks like if I upgrade to commons lang3 version 3.4, they are once again faster.  Now 'unescapeHtml3' is almost twice as fast as 'Html.fromHtml'

Comment: the API in above discussion is deprecated. if you wanna use latest version (3.9 for me), please use org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4 or unescapeHtml3 to unescape it after import it inside android by adding => implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.6' instead.

Answer (score 3):

`fromHtml()` does not have a high-performance HTML parser, and I have no idea how quick the `toString()` implementation on `SpannedString` is. I doubt either were designed for your scenario.

Ideally, the strings are clean before they get to a low-power phone. Either clean them up in the build process (for resources/assets), or clean them up on a server (before you download them).

If, for whatever reason, you absolutely need to clean them up on the device, you can perhaps use the NDK to create a C/C++ library that does the cleaning for you faster.

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't be able to get them cleaned up before they arrive on the device.  I don't suppose you know of any libraries that are already available?

Answer (score 3):

This is an incredibly fast and simple option:
[Unbescape](https://github.com/unbescape/unbescape)

It greatly improved our parsing performance which requires every string to be run through a decoder.

Comment: Just tried a simple benchmark a while ago. `Html.fromHtml()` took 27.501 seconds to finish, versus 3.015 seconds for `HtmlEscape.unescapeHtml()` for the exact same test batch. It's a very significant improvement indeed. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Comment: That is only for JavaScript not Java though...?

Comment: I was wondering if the regex answers might suit. You'd have to put some code around it, but the regex is the tricky bit. I guess it depends how complex the html is going to be

Answer (score 0):

> With a large batch of these it can add
>   over a minute

Any parsing will take some time. 22ms seems to me like fast.
Anyway, can you do it in background? Can help you some kind of caching?

Comment: It is being done in the background, but it is something the user has to wait for.  Yes, it is an ok speed, but when it has to process a large batch (a couple thousand) it can cause the user to be waiting for over a minute, which is just not great.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not tried them yet, I found some possible solutions:

1. [HTML Java Parsers](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers)
2. [HTML Parsing](http://blog.andrewpearson.org/2010/07/android-html-parsing.html)
3. [More HTML Parsing](http://telyas.com/wordpress2/2009/01/30/android-html-parser/)

I hope it helps.