# How can I Decode string?

Tags: java, android

I have string like `"&amp;auml;s&amp;aring;"` that needs to be converted like "äså"
so how can we do that?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918920/decode-html-entities-in-android

Comment: I have checked again but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double-unescape the string, using commons-lang `StringEscapeUtils`:

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is working then one simplest thing you can do is enclose whatever string you have within   and do a xml parse using the SAX Parser on the device. This will give you a callback to decode xml entities wherein you can replace the characters. There are a lot of places wherein you can get a map.

Answer (score -1):

you may try Uri.decode(yourString)