# is there any way to decode string?

Tags: java, android, html

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How can I Decode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990943/how-can-i-decode-string)
>   [Java: How to decode HTML character entities in Java like HttpUtility.HtmlDecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode)

Hi,

I have string like as an eg **"&auml;s&aring;"** that needs to be converted like this **"äså"** pls help me out here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I Decode string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990943/how-can-i-decode-string) You already asked this question.

Comment: It is _not_ a duplicate. He is having a concrete problem that is different from the one in the target thread. Perhaps he is giving the wrong data, but with the given data the question differs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [`StringEscapeUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) class in the Apache Commons library. (Specifically the [`unescapeHtml` method](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29)).

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "&auml;s&aring;";
        System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(str)); // prints äså
    }
}
```