# How to convert special characters, "Fran%c3%a7ais" -> "Français"?

Tags: java, android, encoding, character-encoding, encode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do URL decoding in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138127/how-to-do-url-decoding-in-java)

I have string "Fran%c3%a7ais". How can I convert it to correct "Français" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [URLDecoder](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html):

`URLDecoder.decode(String s)`

According to the Docs the function is deprecated, so you'll need to use this one:

```
public static String decode(String s, String enc) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
```

Example:

```
String decoded = URLDecoder.decode("Fran%c3%a7ais", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: This method is deprecated. You can use `URLDecoder.decode("Fran%c3%a7ais", "UTF-8");`

Comment: @assylias I edited that and mentioned about the encoding scheme parameter. That is not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like percent-encoded UTF-8. For each maximal sequence of (percentsign)+(hex digit)+(hex digit), first convert it to bytes by taking each pair of hex digits to encode a byte; then interpret the resulting byte sequence as the UTF-8 encoding as the actual text.

Comment: This is overly complex and could be already been done with the API.

Comment: @ihsoyih: The answer describes what the implementation of the API does, which is useful to know even if one doesn't, for the time being, need to code it explicitly.