# ASCII Character Decryption

Tags: java, string, ascii, mime, url-encoding

I have a large string of ASCII decimals with percents preceding (example: `"%40%3e%20%12"` except much larger).

How can I analyze this String to extract all of the actual characters out of it?

Comment: 3e doesn't look like a decimal. Is it urlencoded? Then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138127/how-to-do-url-decoding-in-java

Comment: call `split("%")` on your String

Comment: This is the solution, my apologies for duplicating an issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138127/how-to-do-url-decoding-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want:

```
java.net.URLDecoder.decode(str, "UTF-8")
```