# Decode URL whereas encoded string are in double quotes

Tags: java

I have an URL like this:

```
localhost:8080/demo?xml=hello"&lt;xyz&gt;&#xa";
```

here I want to decode `&lt;` and `&gt;` `&#xa;`

Comment: I have a large string and can have multiple encoded string ? how can we achive it ?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138127/how-to-do-url-decoding-in-java

Answer (score 2):

From apache Common -[`StringEscapeUtils#escapeHtml()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) can simplify your job.

```
String string= StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(encodedString);
```

Answer (score 1):

First extract the part you want to decode:

```
 String str = url.substring(str.indexOf('"') + 1, str.lastIndexOf('"'));
```

Then decode it using [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29):

```
 String result = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are able to extract the String between quotes in the URL. Then you could use **Apache Commons Lang** ([StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29)) to unescape special entities:

```
String unescapedString = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4("&lt;xyz&gt;&#xa");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use methods provided by Apache Commons Lang

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
// ...
String afterDecoding = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(beforeDecoding);
```