# Encode a URL for proper characters

Tags: java, url-encoding

I have a URL that looks like below:

```
https://www.xyz.net/test%3Fkey%3Dvalue
```

How do I encode it to look like below:

```
https://www.xyz.net/test?key=value
```

I guess I need to use the URL Encoding techniques or?

Comment: actually you need to decode it, but you're on the right way indeed. Keep on going, try some code and come back here if you get stuck.

Comment: It is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138127/how-to-do-url-decoding-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java.net.URLDecoder.decode(resourceURL, "UTF-8") is the answer!