# Replacing symbol in URL won't Work

Tags: java, android, http, replaceall

I am trying to display an image in android by receiving the url from the web server and then turning it to a bitmap image but getting the following error as the symbol %5C is in it.

```
E/Error﹕ http:%5C/%5C/thumbs3.ebaystatic.com%5C/pict%5C/3007385805144040_5.jpg
```

I have tried `url2.replaceAll("%5C","");` to get rid of the symbol but this has no effect at all. How can I get rid of it so I have a valid url.

Comment: Did you not assign the result of calling `replaceAll` back to `str2`? Strings are immutable in Java - just calling `replaceAll` and ignoring the result will have no effect. Having said that, I would take a close look at *why* you're getting that data to start with - there may well be better approaches.

Comment: You need to assign the result to the same String

Comment: like this String newUrl = url.replaceAll("%5C", "");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is a called URL Decoding.

Read more here: [How to do URL decoding in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138127/how-to-do-url-decoding-in-java)

Don't try manually replacing yourself, use a library or *write your own for all `cases`*:

```
import java.net.URLDecoder;

String result = URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
```

**Java 1.7+:**

```
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

String result = URLDecoder.decode(url, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
```

Comment: was in the process of posting roughly this :)

Comment: But in this case `URLDecoder.decode()` just change `"%5C"` back to `'\\'`

Comment: @timrau In Java, like many languages, the first \\ "escapes" the following character, therefore \\ -> \.

Answer (score 1):

```
String url = "http:%5C/%5C/thumbs3.ebaystatic.com%5C/pict%5C/3007385805144040_5.jpg";
        String newUrl = url.replaceAll("%5C", "");
```

Now try the newUrl as your path.
If the problem is with URL then this will help you, otherwise the problem coming from when you decode the url to bitmap.