# Conversion from UTF-8 to actual character in java

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

I am sending a parameter string value, a french character "**ç**", to my web service in JAVA thorough GET method. In java, it is shown in UTF-8 encoded form as **%C3%A7**.

How can I convert it back to the same french character during the execution itself?

Comment: By using UTF-8 as the expected encoding on the page. You need to be more explicit about the technology you use for the web service if you want a specific answer.

Comment: I'm using REST for the web service.

Let's forget the web service for once, I already have the string in UTF-8 encoded form (think of it as hard coded) in my code and now I want to convert it into normal text and I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: " In java, it is shown in UTF-8 encoded form as %C3%A7." - and how are you doing that exactly? How do you obtain the data, and how do you print it?

Comment: I'm obtaining the data as part of Input JSON. I'm printing it in JAVA using System.out.println();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do URL decoding in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138127/how-to-do-url-decoding-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tha answer you nned is the one liked by @Joe; you need to "convert" the query string:

```
String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
```

It's not a matter of UTF-8 econding, rather a url enconding one.

A side note: in the comments you stated that you are passing the data via GET, if the semantic of the web service is to modify the data I suggest to use the POST method.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for :)