# Spring MVC with Spring Integration HTTP: how to pass the queryString avoiding the "?" encoding with "%3F" ?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I have two **Spring MVC** applications interconneted between each others with **Spring Integration HTTP**.

I have an **"application1"** and an **"application2"**.

The *application1* receive this HTTP GET request:

```
http://localhost:8080/application1/api/persons/search/findByName?name=Name
```

The *application1* manage the request with this `@Controller`:

```
@Controller
public class ApplicationController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/{repository}/search/{methodName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void search(@PathVariable(value="repository") String repository, 
                       @PathVariable(value="methodName") String methodName, 
                       ModelMap model, 
                       HttpServletRequest request, 
                       HttpServletResponse response) {                     
        // handling the request ...
    }
}
```

Here is what I can see in the request properties:

```
getRequestURI=/application1/api/persons/search/findByName
getRequestedSessionId=null
getContextPath=/application1
getPathTranslated=null
getAuthType=null
getMethod=GET
getQueryString=name=Name
getServletPath=/api/persons/search/findByName
getPathInfo=null
getRemoteUser=null
```

I want to *"transfer"* this request to the **application2** using Spring Integration HTTP with an `<int-http:outbound-gateway>`.

The message for the channel used by the outbound-gateway is originated in the `@Controller` in this way:

```
MessagingChannel messagingChannel = (MessagingChannel)appContext.getBean("requestChannelBean");
String payload = repository+"/search/"+methodName;
Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload).build();
MessageChannel requestChannel = messagingChannel.getRequestChannel();
MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate = new MessagingTemplate();
Message<?> response = messagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(requestChannel, message);
```

This is the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` configuration:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="gateway" rest-template="restTemplate"
    url="http://localhost:8080/application2/api/service/{pathToCall}"
    http-method="POST" header-mapper="headerMapper" extract-request-payload="true"
    expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
    <int-http:uri-variable name="pathToCall" expression="payload"/>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

This gateway produces an HTTP POST request towards the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/application2/api/service/persons/search/findByName
```

But in this request **I lose the original QueryString** received by the *application1*.

I have tried to **add the queryString directly to the payload** as follows:

```
String queryString = "";
if (request.getQueryString()!=null)
    queryString = request.getQueryString();
String payload = repository+"/search/"+methodName+"?"+queryString;
```

But this doesn't work: the produced url is:

```
http://localhost:8080/application2/api/service/persons/search/findByName%3Fname=Name
```

**The "?" symbol is replaced by "%3F"**, so the called method is `"/service/persons/search/findByName%3Fname=Name"`, instead of `"/service/persons/search/findByName"`

I suppose that it depends on the `http-method="POST"`; I want to use the POST method in any case, because I want to use this "service" for general requests.

So what I have to do in order to transfer the queryString of the original request to the other side in the simplest way as possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say that the behaviour of application1 is valid - to encode the payload. It should rather be application2's responsibility to decode it properly (change `%3F` back to `?`). Do you have control over application2?

Comment: Yes, sure. I have the control of both applications.

Comment: This might help you then: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6138127/466738

Comment: You have right Adam: it's the application1 that encodes the URL, and I have understood why. I also have found the way to avoid the URI encoding: it's enough to set the `encode-uri="false"` in the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` configuration (the default is "true").

Answer (score 4):

I have found the answer.

The encoding of the "?" into "%3F" was made by the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` beacuse the `encode-uri="false"` attribute was missing.

The outbound gateway encodes the URI by default, because the `encode-uri` attribute is setted to true by default.