# Whats wrong with char set?

Tags: javascript, java, json, character-encoding

Try make request data from JavaScript to Java using JSON format.
Request body in JavaScript looks like:

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Chicken pasta",
    "description": "Lets make chicken pasta",
    "category": "Unassigned",
    "favorite": true,
    "prepTime": "",
    "cookTime": "",
    "ingredients": [
        {}
    ],
    "steps": [],
    "user": {
        "id": "2",
        "username": "user2"
    }
}
```

But on server side (in my Java controller) it is:

```
%7B%0A%09%22id%22%3A+%223%22%2C%0A%09%22name%22%3A+%22Chicken+pasta%22%2C%0A%09%22description%22%3A+%22Lets+make+chicken+pasta%22%2C%0A%09%22category%22%3A+%22Unassigned%22%2C%0A%09%22favorite%22%3A+true%2C%0A%09%22prepTime%22%3A+%22%22%2C%0A%09%22cookTime%22%3A+%22%22%2C%0A%09%22ingredients%22%3A+%5B%0A%09%09%7B%7D%0A%09%5D%2C%0A%09%22steps%22%3A+%5B%5D%2C%0A%09%22user%22%3A+%7B%0A%09%09%22id%22%3A+%222%22%2C%0A%09%09%22username%22%3A+%22user2%22%0A%09%7D%0A%7D=
```

So I'm getting JSON parsing exception.
So how encode it?

Comment: its encoded you have to decode it

Comment: use JSON.stringify() method to convert javascript object to json string

Comment: Used it already, string you see on JS side is JSON.stringify(object)

Comment: Suggest looking into how to decode request data with mime type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in java - seems to be more of a java question.

Comment: The string you receive on the server is URL encoded. You need to URL decode it before you can parse it as JSON. See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138127/how-to-do-url-decoding-in-java) about URL decoding in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you receive on the server is URL encoded. You need to URL decode it before you can parse it as JSON. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138127/how-to-do-url-decoding-in-java) about URL decoding in java.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Thomas, you right and I've found it out already. But did not used URLDecoder.decode, just wrote my own couple strings of code :)

```
   public static String toDecimal (String hexStr) {
        char[] hex = hexStr.toCharArray();
        char current;
        String result = "";
        for (int i=0;i<hex.length;i++) {
            if (hex[i] == '%') {
                current = (char) ((toDecimal(hex[i+1]) * 16) + toDecimal(hex[i+2]));
                i+=2;
            } else {
                if (hex[i] == '+') {
                    current = ' ';
                } else {
                    current = hex[i];
                }
            }
            result += current;
        }
        while (!(result.endsWith("}") || result.endsWith("]"))) {
            result = result.substring(0, result.length()-1);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static int toDecimal (char hex) {
        switch (hex) {
            case '0': return 0;
            case '1': return 1;
            case '2': return 2;
            case '3': return 3;
            case '4': return 4;
            case '5': return 5;
            case '6': return 6;
            case '7': return 7;
            case '8': return 8;
            case '9': return 9;
            case 'A': return 10;
            case 'B': return 11;
            case 'C': return 12;
            case 'D': return 13;
            case 'E': return 14;
            case 'F': return 15;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Same result as mentioned earlier URLDecoder.decode method, but my function also deletes all chars from end while not found end of Json ('}' or ']'), I have no idea why, but I'm getting string from JS ends with '=' symbol.