# Read file on target/test-classes FileNotFound

Tags: java

I´m reading a file from my resource folder in a unit test

I can see the file in the target/test-classes

But when I try to wrap the file into a fileInputStream this one throw the exception because cannot find the file

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("CV.pdf").getFile());
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)
```

Output debuging:

classLoader.getResource("CV.pdf"):

```
file:/Users/Development/File%20-%20Test%20Java%20trial/Code/target/test-classes/CV.pdf
```

Maybe it could be because my folder has whitespace names?

The file is there for sure, I can seen it in that folder.

What I´m doing wrong here?.

Regards.

Comment: Well what is the value in the URL that `getResource(...)` is returning? What values does the `getFile` call return? What is the file path that ends up in `file`?

Comment: I update my question with the output

Comment: The path is URL encoded, you need to decode it http://stackoverflow.com/q/6138127/2670892

Comment: **Do not** decode that URL.  It is correct the way it is!  The problem is that the URL.getFile() method **does not** convert a URL to a file name, it just returns a URL’s path portion.  You should not be trying to convert the URL to a file at all, since you won’t be able to run from a .jar if you do that.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need [FileInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)?

Actual file can be even inside jar (if you instruct maven to make test-jar).

More flexible way is to use [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) instead:

```
try(final InputStream is = getClass().getResource("CV.pdf").openStream()) 
{
    //Do something with is
}
```

Comment: You can also just do `getClass().getResourceAsStream("CV.pdf")`.