# Is there a String-Builder for URL's in java?

Tags: java

Is there a String bulder for URL's similar the UriComponentsBuilder? Because the blanks in my URL-String are replaced with `%20`.

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder
    .fromPath("/test")
    .queryParam("param", "param 1");
String urlWithParams = builder.build().encode().toUriString();
```

The Result of urlWithParams is `/test?param=param%201` but I need `/test?param=param 1`

My current workaround is `urlWithParams.replace("%20", " ");`

Comment: You can't have spaces in URLs, they have to be encoded. In other words, UriComponentsBuilder is doing the right thing. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space

Comment: Usually web frameworks have similar. Do You use some? BTW. manually connecting can have more problems, not only %20. One of answers is use URLEncode

Comment: It appears to me that you are trying to get something invalid (URI with spaces). Not sure if I can understand correctly; If you are about to build String - perhaps you should use StringBuilder? If you are trying to decode spaces etc. - check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138127/how-to-do-url-decoding-in-java

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: i use the RestTemplate.exchange Function. I cant use the URI parameter becourse in the last step i combine the base path with the expanded path like "http://server/domain" + urlWithParams. This will be done in another Class.

Comment: The URLDecoder works perfect. Thanks a lot for the link Vito.