# String replacement with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, security, web

Some of my sites sometimes get encoded url queries which will redirect to a error page but i would like to support some of these.

With htaccess how could you replace a url like this:

http://website.com/%3Fpage%3Dbdyb2y21ybar3h35

With this:

http://website.com/?page=bdyb2y21ybar3h35

Edit: I would like to do this directly within the .htaccess rather than decode with PHP etc.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6138183/7680884). I think that is what you are searching for

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to do a decode in java or php etc but directly within the htaccess. I was also hoping if the solution is a general string replace then i could modify it to work with other queries etc.

Comment: I think NE flag should solve your problem. Try adding NE to all of your external redirect Rules.