# Can I use sightly display context along with i18n label?

Tags: internationalization, aem, sightly, htl

I am seeing a code in my project as

```
${'myproj.label' @i18n, format=[sighltyObj.field1], context='text'}
```

Intention is pass a variable into i18n text + encode the texts safely. Is this right to use display context along with i18n translations? When I tested with a field1 = "Hello%20World", it is NOT encoding the texts rather rendering as is. 
How can I encode html strings while passing the arguments as variables into i18n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTL will not *decode* the text returned by `format`. I think the confusion comes from the documentation which states for the display context `text` the following:

> Use this for simple HTML content - Encodes all HTML

(Source: [HTL Specification Section 1.2.1 Display Context](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#121-display-context))

But this does not mean that this context *decodes* anything, it *encodes* HTML tags.

So if `sighltyObj.field1` is `Hello%20World` it will *not* be rendered as `Hello World` but as `Hello%20World` as you already noticed.

The display context `text` will *encode* all HTML tags in the given text so that you can't "smuggle" them into a text (see code injection).

So for example:

`${'<p>This is my text</p>' @ context='text'}`

will create the following HTML

`&lt;p&gt;This is my text&lt;/p&gt;`

Note how the `p` tags were *encoded*:

`<p>` became `&lt;p&gt;` and `</p>` became `&lt;/p&gt`.

The getter for `field1` in your `sighltyObj` will have to do the *decoding* so that `Hello%20World` becomes `Hello World`. There is already a answer on Stackoverflow that shows you how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6138183/190823

`String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");`

Comment: Sorry @Jens, in my data dictionary, I had defined the curly braces. Issue is, when the value to field1 is say 'Hello%20World', I am expecting to render as 'Hello World'. But is printed as encoded value only as 'Hello%20World'. Can I use the 'text' display context in conjunction with i18n to format and decode the label text?

Comment: @SaravanaPrakash Now I get your question. I have updated my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @Jens