# Android display human readable string

Tags: java, android

I have the following `string: Don%E2%80%99t%20Have%20a%20Login?` how to convert it to human readable format?

Comment: is it encrypted form ?

Comment: Woot... this is awesome... `spontaneous growth of random generated code. A true miracle by ...App X`. Program name and version please that produced your string.

Answer (score 1):

The text is url encoded. To decode, use the `URLDecoder`

```
String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6138183/1392490)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in String,

```
String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
```

If you want it in text form then

It's simple.

- Open [NotePad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

-> Paste your string and select all text.

-> Go to **Plugins**.

-> Go to **MIME Tools**

-> Click **URL Decode**

**Simple** :-)

[image]