# Java string contains hex characters

Tags: java, string, hex

I'm working in java and I have a string that contains:

```
"Tom %26 Jerry"
```

I get it from a text area. I don't want this, I want:

```
"Tom & Jerry";
```

How can I do?

Thank you very much.

**Finaly I resolved the problem. I found the solution here [How to do URL decoding in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138127/how-to-do-url-decoding-in-java)**

**I have done the following:**

```
name = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(name, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: System.out.println("Tom \u0026 Jerry"); will print "Tom & Jerry" if that's what you're asking

Comment: sorry maybe my explanation it's not good. I have a string that contains "Tom %26 Jerry" but I don't set it i get from a text area.

Comment: It looks url encoded, if you url decode it you should get the clean string

Comment: Thank you very much @Juan, I searched information about this and I have been able to solve the problem.