# URL that contain the ? is changed automaticaly to %3F with thymeleaf

Tags: java, url, thymeleaf

I read many URLs from database through Java Spring Boot and thymleaf expression. And if the URL has "?" it changed automaticaly to "%3F" for instance the URL: www.myserver.de?id=3 will be www.myserver.de%3Fid=3 I think I can't use this solution link because the URLs are readen from DB with Params

< a th:href="@{//{link}(link=${link})}" target="_blank">  For more information click here < /a >

Answer (score 0):

Your URLs are [url encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) in the database so `?` is represented as `%3F`. If you want to get the original URL from encoded URL you need to [url decode it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6138183/1602555) e.g. by doing:

```
String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: I make a debug and a link has the right link with ?
String link;
    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can decode it back to what was your original url.

If you are using java use `java.net.URLDecoder`.

[More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138127/how-to-do-url-decoding-in-java)

Comment: I did that but I got the same problem. 
I think the problem with thymeleaf expression.
In thymeleaf tutorial this
<a th:href="@{/order/{id}/details(id=3,action='show_all')}">

would output as:

<a href="/order/3/details?action=show_all">

but I can not do the same because I reade the URLs from DB

Answer (score 0):

If you are just reading complete URLs straight from the database, you shouldn't be using Thymeleaf standard url syntax (as it's designed to escape URL parameters).  You should just do something like:

```
<a th:href="|//${link}|" target="_blank">For more information click here</a>
```