# Which is the best way to decode URL in java?

Tags: java, urlencode, encoder, urldecode

I use URLDecode/URLEncoder class like this:

```
String decodeStr = URLDecoder.decode(str, "UTF-8");
```

but my security tools says `Avoid dangerous J2EE API`, and use

```
Encoder.encodeForURL()/decodeForURL()
```

instead of

```
URLDecoder.decode()
```

So please anyone can suggest for this point

1. Is `URLDecoder.decode()` not secure?
2. Why this is happening ?
3. Any other security classes are available for encoding and decoding ?

Comment: Kindly refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138127/how-to-do-url-decoding-in-java

Comment: What security tool would that be, and why not ask them?

Comment: **Rubbish.** (However URLDecoder.decode(strI) without charset is wrong.) org.owasp.esapi.Encoder.decodeForURL tests for double URL encoding too, and and rearranges the string a bit, but your form is absolutely alright.

Comment: 1. No. 2. Error in your tool. `URLDecoder` is not a J2EE class, for a start. 3. No necessity for that.

Comment: @Andreas i use kiuwan tool for my security defect , its give me this defect please refer this link  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI_Secure_Coding_Guideline#Banned%20APIs

Comment: @user207421 if your answer is no of first question so please can you explain this

Comment: The tool will also say that `System.out.println()` is "dangerous", and should be replaced with `Logger.*`. I mean, sure, a webapp *should* log to a file, but calling it dangerous is a bit of a stretch. --- Similarly, they [claim](https://static.javadoc.io/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.0.1/org/owasp/esapi/package-summary.html) that `Encoder` fixes "Injection Flaws". I don't see how the *decoder* can be a source of injection vulnerability. --- The list of [Banned APIs](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI_Secure_Coding_Guideline#Banned%20APIs) is **ludicrous**.

Comment: Q. 'Is `URLDecoder.decode()` not secure?'. A. No, it is not 'not secure'. It is secure. It is in fact part of a security/ambiguity solution whose other half is `URLEncoder`. Your tool is out of its mind. Find a better one.