# how to retreive data(present in JSON or anyother format) from a url in springboot?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I want to hit a URL which contains data, i want to retreive this data using spring boot and convert it to AVRO format. data needs to be picked up in JSON format

Comment: You might find something usefull on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-avro-confluent.

Answer (score 0):

data and url in one sentence raises alarm. Unless you have a particular need (usually legacy reasons) to use URL to send data, use requestbody for sending the data.
Remember, many browsers will have URL character limit even though http protocol doesn't talk about any

If you are adamant about sending Jsondata using url, either look into base64encode it and send and then base64decode it on serverside.
Or do URL encoding and [Decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138127/how-to-do-url-decoding-in-java) . Because there is a highchance that the data might not be URL-safe