# Decode URL in Genexus Procedure (Web Service)

Tags: http, web-services, twilio, genexus

I receive input data like that into a web service developed using a Genexus Procedure:
`SmsMessageSid=SM7e1ab417617176ec9936788235aaf020&NumMedia=0&ProfileName=Checho&SmsSid=SM7e1ab417617176ec9936788235aaf045&WaId=5699999999&SmsStatus=received&Body=**Este+es+un+texto+lago+que+incluye+%3A+%25+.+%F0%9F%99%82+%28emoji%29**&To=whatsapp%3A%2B189898886&NumSegments=1&ReferralNumMedia=0&MessageSid=SM7e1ab417617176ec9936788235aaf020&AccountSid=ACfda172076a87805952e99b3be82007d9&From=whatsapp%3A%2B56975495288&ApiVersion=2010-04-01`

I need access to Body parameter, but it has url format.
It's necessary to convert body's value to a clear text.

Regards!

Genexus has URLEncode function, but it's necessary the reverse function.
[Genexus functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH9UW.png)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular expression to search the url

```
&pattern = '&Body=\w*&' //CHECK THIS!!
&rslt = &url.Matches(&pattern)
```

Check the documentation of regular expressions with genexus and adapt the pattern that you have to look for. https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?4606,Regular+Expressions+%28RegEx%29

Comment: I think it's useful for find Body variable. However, I need to convert value of Body variable in decoded URI. On the other hand, Genexus provides URLEncode but it doesn't exist in Genexus functions.

Answer (score 0):

To decode the URL I would recommend the use of native code.

For example: [How to do URL decoding in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138127/how-to-do-url-decoding-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by writing native code and using GxClasses methods:

```
JAVA [!&decodedUrl!] = GXutil.URLDecode([!&url!]);

CSHARP [!&decodedUrl!] = GXUtil.UrlDecode([!&url!]);
```