# How to convert file path from string

Tags: android, file, android-intent, path

I'm getting a path in string into second activity from frist Activity after completing the onActivity results. And I'm getting them like this

`content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDCIM%2FScreenshots%2Ffilename.jpg`

But i want this

`content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshot/filename.jpg`

how i can get this please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do URL decoding in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138127/how-to-do-url-decoding-in-java)

Comment: .replace("%2F", "/").

Comment: But why do you want it like that? It looks you took the wrong way. A dead end.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer

```
public String decodeString(String pathstring)
{
    String decodedString="";
    try {
        decodedString = URLDecoder.decode(pathstring,"UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    }
    return decodedString;
}
```