# string from string.xml shows different behaviour for different views

Tags: android, string

Declared Resource String in **string.xml** file.

```
<string name="beta">&#946;</string>
```

When I try to set this text to **TextView** it Displays properly β,

but if when I set this in to **Button** then it Displays **B**.

Why its behavior is different for different Views ??

Comment: its a binary digit of B thats why its convert into Beta .

Comment: yes but why it shows differently for different views

Comment: ite automatically convert by the OS.

Comment: Might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918920/decode-html-entities-in-android

Comment: it shows because &#946; is **B** in Java Data.  refer: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3b2/index.htm

Comment: for textview it shows β but for button it shows B...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in Button `textAllCaps` property is `true` by default, do it false then it will show β in button also:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="@string/beta" />
```