# Reading XML file containing link (Android)

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I would like to know how to read XML on Android without using XMLPullParser.
I already tried XMLPullParser from this link https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html. It is working. It just due to my requirements, I need to read web service returns XML data in "**String format**" and do the processing later (not at the time I connect to HttpUrlConnection).

Right now, I am using below code and it is reading all XML data correctly except URL link in "link" tag.

```
    val inputStream = urlCon.inputStream
    reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))

    builder = StringBuilder()
    var line: String? = reader.readLine()
    while (line != null) {
        builder.append(line)
        builder.append("\n")
        line = reader.readLine()
    }
```

Here is the return XML that I got from above.
[image: XML return from BufferedReader]

By right, it should be in this https://internalws.factory.com/wh/entry?requestID=admin&id=TD12011101 format.

Any suggestion (java or Kotlin is ok for me) on my reading part? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a few days, I managed to find the answer. 
Previously, I was too focus in `UrlDecoder` that's why I could not find a correct answer.
 
Actually the return was in Html Code format, I need to convert this Html code to normal readable string by using **`Html.fromHtml`**.

From this post, I got my answer >> https://stackoverflow.com/a/40871051/770989

It also explains on how to use it correctly since this function is deprecated after API v24.